# How to Run the command or script through any user in linux?

Tags: shell-script, c, setuid, suid

I am having a C executable in AIX system by which I can run the command through any user like root or system users. script having below permissions.

On AIX server

```
lrwsrwxrwx 1 root system   24    Mar 2016 /var/srty/bin/switchuseridprogram -> /opt/switchuseridprogram
-rwsr-sr-x 1 root mrc    5024 Jul 20 2015 /opt/switchuseridprogram
```

Example usage

```
/var/srty/bin/switchuseridprogram root 'chown mtest1:dba /mprt/setup/test.log'
```

Now I am preparing one RHEL system and I don't have source code of that C executable, and I want to use the same functionality in that RHEL system without using `sudo`.

How to do it?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `sudo`? You do know it can be configured to permit only certain users or groups to run riot commands, don't you. And also that it doesn't have to require a password. (Unless you want it to.)

Comment: You have limited options without sudo or the source to your program. Reinventing your program is out-of-scope here.

Answer (score 2):

Try `sudo`.  For example:

```
sudo chown mtest1:dba /mpart/setup/test.log
```

For more details on how to use and configure `sudo` run `man sudo`.